# In UK, can religious institutions discriminate against the sexual orientation of their own clergy?

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination, religion

There is [this other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18355/can-religious-institutions-discriminate-when-selecting-their-own-clergy) about the same subject but it is applicable to the United States. In this question I want to ask about UK employment laws.

This is in consideration of the United Kingdom employment equality law, about which [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_employment_equality_law) says:

> As an integral part of UK labour law it is **unlawful to discriminate
>   against** a person because they have one of the "protected
>   characteristics", which are, age, disability, gender reassignment,
>   marriage and civil partnership, race, religion or belief, sex, and
>   **sexual orientation**.

In this case I was looking at articles such as [this one](https://www.theguardian.com/law/2012/jul/12/catholic-church-loses-apeal-liability) about a 2012 court case against the Catholic Church in UK, in which the solicitor Tracey Emmott (of Emmott Snell) is quoted as saying:

> "The relationship between a bishop and a priest of a Roman Catholic
>   diocese has many of the hallmarks of an employment relationship, and
>   therefore it is right and proper that the church should be held
>   legally accountable for abuse by its priests."

According to above statement it seems that at least in some cases the position of a priest with the parent church is viewed as an "employment relationship". What I am curious about is what the UK employment law would say about the relationship in cases where a gay priest decides to "come out". **In this kind of situation, is the employment of the priest protected by UK law, or not?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Religious institutions who are employers are allowed to discriminate in a way that would be unlawful for other employers to the extent that the discrimination is in line with their official religious dogma.

[Discrimination at work - exceptions relating to religion and belief](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/discrimination-at-work/what-doesn-t-count-as-discrimination-at-work/discrimination-at-work-exceptions-relating-to-religion-and-belief/)